# Form button only works when Logged in the WP backend

Tags: javascript, contact-form-7

I have a custom-made contact form that only works when a user is logged in, in the backend. For all non-logged-in users, a disabled icon pops up when trying to click on the submit button.

I tried deleting cache, and deactivating all plugins to see whether that's causing the issue. But the issue still persists.

Can someone please help me out here?

This is the page I need help with - https://www.writtenlyhub.com/contact/

Answer (score 0):

```js
window.onload = function() {
 
  const $form = document.querySelector('form');
  $form.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log('prevented submit by code for demo');
  });
};
```

Did you not payed your developer? That code looks intentionally put there.

Comment: But if I remove this code, My mandatory fields are not validated. Meaning even if the email is not submitted, the form is being accepted. Could you please help me with that.